# Install Python package from GitHub using PyCharm

Tags: python, github, pycharm

I created a VirtualEnv in PyCharm to install my Python packages. I wanted to install this fork of the django project from GitHub.

https://github.com/django-nonrel/django

For packages available from [PyPI](https://pypi.python.org/pypi) I would normally use the built-in search tool in PyCharm, but I'm not sure how to correctly install it into the VirtualEnv within PyCharm from GitHub. Would anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Please see Gord Thompson's answer for an approach to get this working with Pycharm.**

Here's an alternative of how to get this to work without it:

Clone the repository:

```
git clone https://github.com/django-nonrel/django.git my_folder
```

The install it manually into your virtualenv:

```
cd my_folder
python setup.py build
python setup.py install
```

Comment: thanks, but I don't think this will work as python setup.py will just build it to the main python installation not the VE used by PyCharm.

Comment: just use the full path to your virtualenv's python, like in /home/user/virtualenv/python /home/user/download/package/setup.py install

Comment: The question was how to install a package from a git repository with pycharm.  This doesn't answer that question.  The answer should be 'You can't'.  And where did you get the idea that using the package manager tool with pycharm will make you 'become dependent on it'.  In many cases using pycharm is more convenient to add a package than dropping into a command line and finding the correct interpreter and installing the package.

Comment: @KyleGobel no, this is a X-Y problem. Actually you can install packages from pycharm, it just isn't helpful to anyone to stick with it.

Comment: @Alvaro I came to this question seeing how/if it was possible to install a package with the pycharm ide from a git repo (i.e ``pip install git://github.com/package`` but with pycharm), I imagine everyone who visits this question's intent is the same.  It's disappointing to see an answer that doesn't answer the question.  I don't want opinions on what you think are possible alternatives, I wanted the answer to the question.  If there is a way to do what the question is asking, maybe you could add that to your answer and then describe what you feel is a better way, and why you think it's better

Comment: Also, in most distributions unfortunately PyCharm does NOT recognise packages that have been installed externally and not with PyCharm itself (and you have to back flip jump back and right to make it recognise it).

Comment: You could put `git+https://github.com/django-nonrel/django.git` in `requirements.txt` or `setup.py` and PyCharm will suggest to install `django` if it has not been installed

Comment: @KyleGobel you're right, I'm seeing these comments quite late it seems

I edited the answer to point towards one that actually addresses the question

Answer (score 31):

The following worked for me with PyCharm Community Edition 2018.1 on Xubuntu 16.04:

After loading the project (which was associated with the virtual environment that I wanted to update), I opened PyCharm's Terminal window (<kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>F12</kbd>, or View > Tool Windows > Terminal) and then used the command

```
pip install git+https://github.com/v-chojas/pyodbc@unicodecolumnsize
```

to install pyodbc from the "unicodecolumnsize" branch of the fork maintained by user `v-chojas`.

Once the install was completed the package showed up in the Project Interpreter widow

On OSX+PyCharm 2018.1 needed to restart PyCharm to pick up the change and recognize the imports from the newly installed packages.

If PyCharm does not pick up on the library and places red underlines on your imports, do a File->Invalidate caches/restart and choose invalidate and restart PyCharm.

[image: pycharm.png]

Comment: A quick note: this does work! But if PyCharm doesn't seem to recognize the install (i.e. `import` can't find the library) try invalidating your cache and restarting.

Comment: Just make sure you enter your venv before you do it, i.e. `source venv/bin/activate`

Answer (score 11):

I was struggling to find a way to do this within the PyCharm UI, but it is possible through the integrated Python console:

1. Load your project with the appropriate VE
2. Under the Tools dropdown, click Python Console
3. Then use pip from within the console:

   ```
   import pip
   pip.main(['install','packagename'])
   ```

Comment: Or use !pip install      at the same Python Console

Answer (score 4):

Alternatively, in console:

```
pip install -e git+https://github.com/%%#egg=Package
```

Comment: This is the correct answer for 2021. The trick is the "-e" option, which updates the current and already installed package.

Answer (score 0):

I was with the same problem, all i did was :  Configure the project interpreter to the Python3 inside the venv/scripts you are using the pip install. 
Remember to activate the venv.
That's it , now you can use the pip install on pycharm or on prompot.
The problem is that even with the "venv/lib/sitepackeges"  in the your project's sys.path the pycharm looks only for the packages where the project interpreter is

Answer (score 0):

I had to use a combination of these answers in pycharm 2021.2.1 community edition. Thanks go to @Mike and @marcjae

1. Load your project with the appropriate VE
2. Under the Tools dropdown, click Python Console
3. Then use pip from within the console:

example : goprocam at http://github.com/konradit/gopro-py-api

```
   import pip
   pip.main(['install','-e','git+http://github.com/konradit/gopro-py-api.git#egg=goprocam']')
```