# How to import packages into Pycharm using PIP?

Tags: python, pip, pycharm

I'm trying to install a package onto Pycharm using PIP. I am running Anacondas on a Pycharm IDE. I know that you use the project interpreter to install packages and I also know that the package should be located under PyPi but when I go to the project interpreter and click add package the package I'm trying to install doesn't appear under the list of available packages.

I know that you can install the package using PIP and I have PIP installed through Anaconda although I am unsure how to run a pip command through Pycharm. I've tried typing it into the cmd console and the python code and neither seems to have any effect...

The package I'm trying to install is: https://github.com/seatgeek/fuzzywuzzy.

The pip command to install it is: `pip install fuzzywuzzy` but I am unsure as to where I'm supposed to run that command.

I'm fairly new at Python so any help would be much appreciated!

Thank you!

Comment: This is strange because i tried to install it and I found it in the package list. Is this the only one that you can't install or do you have the same problem with all packages?

Comment: Other packages are showing up for me. When I search for FuzzyWuzzy it doesn't show up... Is it possible I have PyPi installed incorrectly or something? I"m running Anaconda so I have a lot of packages pre-installed.

Comment: If you try to open a command line (not in pycharm) and try to run pip? is it work or not?

Comment: What do you mean a command line? You mean a non-pycharm version of python, the command prompt? etc.

Comment: Also what command would I run to run pip?

Comment: yes, open a command prompt and run "pip freeze" it's just to understand if pip it's correctly installed

Comment: Says: "'pip' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file."

Answer (score 4):

This is guide for installing the pip packages from Python Console in Pycharm IDE.

## Do not forget to run Pycharm as administrator if you are using windows OS before installing the packages.

First of all import the pacakage of pip in python console.

```
import pip
```

Installation of Package.

```
 pip.main(['install', '<package_name>'])
```

**Examples**
The below command will upgrade the version of package setuptools.

```
pip.main(['install','--upgrade','setuptools'])
```

The below command will install the  scikit-learn and numpy packages.

```
pip.main(['install','numpy','scikit-learn'])
```

The below command will uninstall the scikit-learn package.

```
pip.main(['uninstall','scikit-learn'])
```

[image: Python console snapshot in Pycharm]

Comment: I can't believe this is how you install packages in PyCharm! In VS Code you just open the terminal and can pip install directly from there

Answer (score 3):

I found someone else's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37629063/7065753) that works for me:

You need to use

```html
import pip
pip.main(['install','packagename'])
```

Which allows you to manually install packages through pip using Python code.

Answer (score 0):

I was with the same problem, all i did was :  Configure the project interpreter to the Python3 inside the venv you are using the pip install. 
Remember to activate the venv.
That's it , now you can use the pip install on pycharm or on prompot.
The problem is that even with the "venv/lib/sitepackeges"  in the your project's sys.path the pycharm looks only for the packages where the project interpreter is.