# Requesting steps to install packages from Github to PyCharm

Tags: github, installation, pycharm, package

I am new to Pycharm and Python in general. I am starting with Data science self study using the book Data Science from scratch by Joel Grus. The author has a Github page which has all the required packages to run the code given in the book. I am using Pycharm as my IDE to practice coding in Python.

The author's GitHub page is below. 
https://github.com/joelgrus/data-science-from-scratch

I am trying to install files in PyCharm using the following command in the Pycharm terminal:

pip install git+https://github.com/joelgrus/data-science-from-scratch.git

When I do so, I get an error shown below:

[Pycharm Terminal error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zafGr.jpg)
Can someone help me to fix the steps?

Thanks,
Rohit

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just download the requirements.txt / clone the whole repository first

then run `pip install -r /path/to/requirements.txt`

you want to get the repository anyway right.

Comment: Hi Yohanes, 

I have already cloned using the steps in the link below:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21048073/install-python-package-from-github-using-pycharm.  
It also got installed in the path: C:\Users\1027849\github\data-science-from-scratch\scratch. However, I am unable to reference the package scratch in my code. It may be working directory issue as well. The project folder and the package folder are in two different locations. How do I add the package folder location in Pycharm in my current project directory/folder?

Answer (score 0):

Downloaded the module from author github page. 
The 
File --> Settings --> Project Structure --> Add content Root
I added the file path to the module that was downloaded.
[Pycharm settings screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bYLLv.jpg)